# tag synonyms suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

[`I2C`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/i2c/info) and [`TWI`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/twi/info) should be synonyms, they are the same thing with a different non patented name

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Derivative_technologies

> TWI (Two Wire Interface) or TWSI (Two-Wire Serial Interface) is essentially the same bus implemented on various system-on-chip processors from Atmel and other vendors.[9] Vendors use the name TWI, even though I²C is not a registered trademark. Trademark protection only exists for the respective logo (See upper right corner) and patents on I²C have now lapsed.

---

There is also a [`555`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/555/info) and [`555timer`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/555timer/info) tag, these should either be merged or synonyms.

Comment: Someone didn't agree with the suggestion (down-voted) and since this can not be related to the 555 tags it means that he wants I2C and TWI to remain individual tags. Please explain the benefit of that.

Answer (score 3):

Good idea. Would you use [i2c](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i2c) as displayed tag?

Answer (score 0):

Good idea. Would you use [twi](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twi) as displayed tag?

Answer (score 0):

TWI doesn't really merit becoming a synonym... It only has six questions, most tagged with i2c anyway, most tagged because of Amtel implementation of TWI.

There is only one question that even warrants the tag in the first place, because it is the only one that addresses any difference between proper i2c and Atmel's TWI.

[Why doesn't Atmel TWI support I2C START BYTE on TWI?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66440/why-atmel-twi-doesnt-support-i2c-start-byte-on-twi)

Personally, those 6 questions should just be manually retagged and forget about the synonym...

**As for 555timer, unless they just did it, it's already a synonym.** How many questions were tagged as 555timer anyway? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms shows that it had none. Why add an uncommon synonym when it did not need to be added?

Comment: The synonyms were just made (check the creation date). What you're talking about would be *merging* the tags together, which is not really reversible. If we wanted to eliminate a tag by combining it with another, merging is *much* preferred over manually retagging as it doesn't spam the front page.

Comment: @W5VO 6 questions does not a spam make.

Comment: So rereading it, it seems like you're saying that there is enough difference between I2C and TWI to justify not making them synonyms. In terms of quantity, six questions is a low enough number to justify a synonym. If we (as a site) decide that TWI and I2C should fall into the same bucket, then synonyms are the most community and asker friendly way to enforce that. It's not hard for a mod to make a synonym or merge questions.

Comment: @W5VO What I am saying is that TWI is insignificant, and doesn't merit being a synonym either, in terms of question quality and actual topic relatedness. Only a single TWI tagged question is related to TWI. But aside from that, here's a question. What's the minimum number of questions where a mod initiated merge or synonym should be required? 6? 5? 1?

Comment: My threshold is pretty low - 3 or so. One or two is probably enough to just go fix by editing the questions with the tags (as you suggest), but more than that and it's getting used enough to avoid the auto-tag-delete routine. I wouldn't say it's a *big* problem, but there's a really easy fix so I don't mind. For reference, there were 8 questions tagged [tag:555timer].

Comment: The barrier to entry isn't really the *merging* part, but the *synonym*. Due to the way the StackExchange is set up, synonyms are really hard to put in place without moderator support.