# Should we merge `ne555` and `555timer` tags into `555` tag?

Tags: discussion

There are 120 questions tagged `ne555` and 0 questions tagged with `555timer`.

I don't see the usefulness of these tags. Should they be merged with `555`?

Comment: This question arose upon seeing `ne555` on [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/616499/2028).

Answer (score 12):

I would think 555timer is the most descriptive and should be the main tag. If there are no objections I'll merge them with 555timer

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried to investigate but FYI [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3388) previous Meta question (which unfortunately is mainly about doing things with the I2C / TWI tags) mentions some 555 tag-related stuff, mainly in [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3391) answer. Personally I would not use "555timer" as the master tag - we don't use 741opamp or 7400quadnandgate so why 555timer? I would stick to just the IC number, as I think that is what has become the standard for other IC tags. 555timer and ne555 should be synonyms.

Comment: I agree with @SamGibson to follow the other IC tag conventions, but am not bothered either way. I just noticed what appear to be duplicates and wanted to bring it to attention.

Comment: Update to my previous comment after spending a few more minutes reviewing: It turns out that we *do* have an existing "741-opamp" tag (I looked for "741opamp" which is why I didn't find it when rushing to look earlier). I still don't think that we should include the IC function in a tag name (any tag) and the 7400 tag (to stick with that earlier example) doesn't include any function text in the tag *name*. Perhaps we need to decide that point first i.e. should tag names include text like "timer" "opamp" "adc" etc (and, if necessary, schedule tags like "741-opamp" to be changed to just "741").

Comment: The "timer" suffix would only be useful if there was an entirely different use for 555 that we needed to distinguish it from. Same argument for "741-opamp". I'd agree on just using the IC number part.

Comment: When you merge, if you type in 555 it would rename it to 555timer, which would be clarifying. When you say 555 it's almost always accompanied by the word timer

Comment: @VoltageSpike a 555 has many 'off-label' uses where it does not function as a timer at all. Many years ago I designed a small-run product using the 555 as a kind of window comparator.

Answer (score 11):

I think using the proposed '555' tag is the most inclusive, so, sure, might as well merge them.

(What would [Colin McRae](https://youtu.be/EmDxhv1HsJo) do? What a ‘555’ tag may look like.)

Answer (score 3):

I see the most voted here is saying to put 555timer tag, but that`s not good because its not only a timer, it can be used as frequency divider , in counters, etc.
the problem in merging into a 555timer tag is that every time a person will open a post and try to put 555 as a  flag and only encounter 555timer then the person will create a 555 only tag.

and also by seeing that the 555timer tag already exist and it haves 0 topics, one can see that people creating topics already have this option as a tag and they are choosing to not using it. so it's not a good tag at all. the person wanting to put 555 and timer in flags can just put these two as separate flags. because also theres timers that don't use 555.

Comment: Just FYI, the reason your text is being formatted as code is that you're using the wrong 'single apostrophe' character. You should be using ' which is typically next to " on your keyboard, but instead you're using ` which is typically over near ~.

Comment: edited, yeah it was the accent is because in abnt2 layout the ' is on the position that sits the ` accent in the us layout. i use both so, sometimes i dont notice that is on the other layout and gets the other symbol.

Answer (score 2):

I came to meta to ask the same question and, seeing that there is consensus that [ne555](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ne555) should be merged into [555](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/555), I've done that and made them synonyms. [555timer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/555timer) is also a synonym, but that was already done.

Answer (score -5):

No, we shouldn't. There's 555 questions that are explicitly about the CMOS variants, and nothing else. Most questions only refer to the 555 as concept, not to the NE555 BJT implementation.

555timer and ne555 are *not* synonyms.

Comment: I am glad you pointed that out; however I still do not see the use case for having tags for the variants. Is it likely that someone would search/follow one but not the other?

Comment: hm, fair point, but I'd say in this case, merging the two would actually merge things that have a useful distinction so far, so yes, I can see a case where I'm looking for an answer to link to that uses a CMOS 555. In that case I'd look for `[555] -[NE555]` first, and only after not finding it that way look at the much more mixed-bag-of-quality [tag:NE555] tag.

Comment: You're more optimistic than I am about authors of questions using the correct tag! :)

Comment: I do have an optimistic view on the folks relentlessly editing these questions... You do have a point, though.

Comment: Isn't the NE555 drop in compatible with the LM555? Yeah, they don't have the same characteristics: https://www.apogeeweb.net/circuitry/ne555-vs-lm555-timer-ics-what-is-the-difference.html but you could use one in place of the other?

Comment: it's not about bipolar devices like LM555 but about devices like the TLC555 or the MIC1555

Comment: Are not all of these devices drop in compatible but varying in functionality?

Comment: Couldn't we just tag the relevant questions with both "555" and "CMOS"?

Comment: @VoltageSpike nope, not drop-in compatible. Different speeds, voltages, drive strengths

Comment: @Finbarr point is: currently we have two tags. The questions under these two tags are meaningfully distinct. I.e., seeing one tag and not the other actually carries information. Merging these two tags removes information from the tag system.

Comment: I realise that, but we don't have tags for e.g. 74HC00, 74HCT00, 74LS00 as well as 7400. Does the number of use cases specific to the CMOS variant justify another tag?

Comment: @Finbarr I do agree that this is a super special case. If the tag was to be created today, I'd also vote for not having it separate. But as it is, *yes*, the reality of the two tags carrying information after having been around for years justifies keeping both. There's 877 questions with [tag:555], but without [tag:ne555], but only 72 with [tag:ne555] but without [tag:555]; things aren't symmetrical. Yes, most [tag:ne555] questions are [tag:555] questions, but simply not the other way around. Subsuming all under one tag loses *a lot* of useful data on questions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, wouldn't it only lose data on that part of the [tag:ne555] that are actually, specifically, about NE555, and not about 555 in general? And is that a distinction that's actually worth keeping anyway if the question text specifies _which_ 555 they mean etc.? Tagging all questions on 555s with [tag:ne555] would seem wrong, yes.

Comment: @ilkkachu that would be the case if [tag:ne555] wasn't kind of an indicator of ... "on average, not as great a post"; it's been a while, but in the wake of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486156/is-the-ne555-the-ic-i-need-and-if-not-what-do-i-replace-it-with) I looked up the average scores tags through SE Data explorer, and things weren't great. Often, excluding [tag:ne555] yields to better results.